# Understanding the paths-through-non-attacking-rooks combinatorial model

Tags: combinatorics

In *A Path to Combinatorics for Undergraduates*, the authors prove the following identity in two ways:

$\sum (a_1 a_2\cdots a_n) = (2n-1)!!$

where the sum on the left is over all products of ordered $n$-tuples of integers such that $1 \leq a_i \leq n + 1 - i$ and $a_{i+1} \geq a_i - 1$ for all $i$, and the expression on the right is the double factorial, e.g. $9!! = 9\cdot7\cdot5\cdot3\cdot1$.

I understand the direct proof they give by recursion, but then they introduce a combinatorial model:

"Let $n$ be a positive integer. We are given an $n \times n$ chessboard and $n$ rooks. Let $A$ and $B$ be two points on the edges of the squares determining the chessboard. A *path connecting A and B* is a continuous curve along the edges of the squares of the chessboard with $A$ and $B$ as endpoints. The *length* of the curve is the length of the path. First, [place] all the rooks on the chessboard so that the rooks cannot attack each other. Next, [draw] a path of length $2n$ connecting the top left corner to the bottom right corner of the chessboard so that all of the rooks are on the same side of the path. In how many different ways can [this task be completed]?"

They go on to use a different recursion to show that the answer is $2 \cdot (2n-1)!!$, and they claim that the subset of paths *over* the rooks is a model for $\sum (a_1 a_2\cdots a_n)$ with the conditions given above. I don't see how you can make an argument for the total of number of ways to arrange the rooks and paths to equal this quantity -- can anyone help me understand this model?